# How do u map a value coming in Ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I have data coming in status which i am able to see on my screen .

The data here has 2 values.

Update;
I forgot to add that there is also a underscore coming in the data

```
TEMPORARY_OFFLINE and TEMPORARY_ONLINE.
```

I want to map this to

```
TEMPORARY OFFLINE = Temporary Offline
TEMPORARY ONLINE  = Temporary Online
```

This is what i want to Show on my page instead on showing the data in ALL CAPS

```
Temporary Offline
Temporary Online
```

What function do I use to map the above in angular 1 .

```
<span class="status">{{feature.status}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a filter with this logic and apply it to the view.

Something like this:

```
app.filter('format', function() {
    return function(input) {
      //Lowercase Uppercase logic here
    }
});
```

And in the view:

```
{{feature.status | format}}
```

Hope this helps.